# mp3gain says file is an MPEG Layer II file, not a layer III file

Tags: ffmpeg

Seems not to make a difference what value I pass to -g under these conditions where it complains file is an MPEG Layer II file, not a layer III file

Comment: mpg123 instead.

Comment: There's a learning curve and it says "-g gain, --gain gain [DEPRACATED]" https://linux.die.net/man/1/mpg123

Comment: sudo apt install mpg123